# Does assembler code compiled on a 32bit machine differ from code compiled with "gcc -m32"?

Tags: gcc, x86-64, cpu-architecture, disassembly, objdump

I'm learnin about assembler language right now. The code examples in the book I'm learning from are all compiled on a x86 32bit machine (i think) with gcc. To match my outputs with the one from the book i compiled my simple helloworld.c with "gcc -m32".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
      printf("Hello World!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output i get from running "objdump -D a32.out | grep -A20 main.:" looks like this:

```
0000051d <main>:
51d:    8d 4c 24 04             lea    0x4(%esp),%ecx
521:    83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
524:    ff 71 fc                pushl  -0x4(%ecx)
527:    55                      push   %ebp
528:    89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
52a:    53                      push   %ebx
52b:    51                      push   %ecx
52c:    83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
52f:    e8 ec fe ff ff          call   420 <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>
534:    81 c3 cc 1a 00 00       add    $0x1acc,%ebx
53a:    c7 45 f4 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0xc(%ebp)
541:    eb 16                   jmp    559 <main+0x3c>
543:    83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
546:    8d 83 f0 e5 ff ff       lea    -0x1a10(%ebx),%eax
54c:    50                      push   %eax
54d:    e8 5e fe ff ff          call   3b0 <puts@plt>
552:    83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
555:    83 45 f4 01             addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
559:    83 7d f4 09             cmpl   $0x9,-0xc(%ebp)
55d:    7e e4                   jle    543 <main+0x26>
```

But in the book it looks like this: [image]

It misses the first three lines from the output I get and doesn't look anything like it except for the next two lines. Why is that ? And how can i change my compiler/disassembly settings to make it look alike ?

Comment: Is it doing the same? That's the only requirement from the compiler output.

Comment: not the same compiler so not the same disassembly.

Comment: no reason to assume any two compilers even the same brand to produce the same output.  gnu is built for the target so even if same version/source of gcc it may still produce different results.  one would hope its the same but you just have to try it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same version of gcc configured the same way, running with `gcc -m32`, should be the same whether it's running on an x86-64 host or an i386 host.  Or cross-compiling from an ARM host!

The difference is gcc version and default settings.  (@Employed Russian points out that the major one is that `-fpie` is on by default in your gcc.  Related: [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux))  It's kinda bad that PIE is on by default for 32-bit code, too, not just 64, because the extra overhead is much more significant in 32-bit mode (no RIP-relative addressing.)

---

Besides config stuff like `-fno-pie`, different versions of gcc produce different code.

Anyway, **if you really want to match what's in the book**, try the same version of gcc they used.  (Hopefully they mention that?  If not, look at the year it was published for a rough hint).  **You can try every gcc version back as far as 4.4 on http://gcc.godbolt.org/**.

Here's [a link to your sample code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Aint+main()%7B%0A++++int+i%3B%0A++++for(i%3D0%3Bi%3C10%3Bi%2B%2B)%7B%0A++++++printf(%22Hello+World!!%5Cn%22)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:30.082742316784874,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g447,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),fontScale:0.8957951999999999,libs:!(),options:'-O0+-m32+-fverbose-asm',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+4.4.7+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:74.75247524752476,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+4.4.7',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:25.247524752475247,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g447,filters:(b:'0',binary:'0',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),fontScale:0.8957951999999999,libs:!(),options:'-O0+-m32+-fverbose-asm',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+4.4.7+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),header:(),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:69.91725768321513,l:'2',m:100,n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) on Godbolt with compiler asm output and disassembly of the binary in two separate output panes, both with optimization disabled.

Note that Matt Godbolt configures gcc without the `default-pie` config, but you could use `-fpie` to get asm like you get on your desktop.

---

Note that with un-optimized code, it's more dependent on gcc's internals than if you'd enabled optimization.  i.e. `-O0` kind of gives you a peek under the hood of how gcc "thinks about" your program, because it doesn't even try to optimize.  (Plus it spills/reloads between every statement to support *changing* variables with a debugger; this is part of why it's so slow: it's purposely strapping a ball and chain to your code.  All this extra storing / reloading makes it harder to read; I usually look at `-O2` or `-O3` output.  See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output))

Answer (score 3):

Your compiler is configured to produce position-independent binary by default, and that causes significant divergence from the book. (This is a fairly recent GCC development).

You will get much closer to the book if you disable this:

```
gcc -fno-pie -no-pie -m32 hello.c
```

As others have stated, there is no guarantee that you will get identical code to what's in the book, unless you get exact same compiler built in exactly the same configuration.